# Question on data exchange between libsora and matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, librosa

In order to save a wave spectrum image, a typical code is as following,

###########################

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa.display

y, sr = librosa.load(filename) 

fig = plt.Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
...
librosa.display.specshow(logmelspec, sr=sample_rate, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
fig.savefig('spec.png')
```

The question is, 'fig' is created in Figure class, and is also a parameter for FigureCanvas, librosa.display.specshow is a function belong to librosa.display class.

1. How does fig know the input data for fig.savefig ?
2. How does the data exchange work between 'fig' and 'librosa'?
3. When I run this code, it did save the right image as expected(however, if I build a FileDialog based application, load a new wav file and call 'fig.savefig' again, the image will become random).

Comment: Probably librosa uses matplotlib's "current figure" (the last created figure, or a new empty figure if nothing was created before).  To answer your third question, it would be helpful if you created a minimal working example to make it clear what is called when and how your code fits together. How do you erase the canvas? Do you recreate the dialog at each call? ...?

Comment: Hi @JohanC, for comment length limitation, can not paste whole working example here, it is something like, Mainwindow-->init+button+connect(savewave), then in savewave function call QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames, to open wav file and call function '    def SaveWave(self):
        y, sr = librosa.load(filename)
        #in this function, there is no need to draw plot
        fig = plt.Figure()
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        ...
        librosa.display.specshow(logmelspec, sr=sample_rate, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
        fig.savefig('spec.png')   '

Comment: "Do you recreate the dialog at each call?"  --Yes.

Comment: Please, don't put code into comments. Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74769933/edit) your post and provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi @JohanC, "matplotlib's "current figure"" as you mentioned, so I just tried to clear and close plot every time, it seems work! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following way can fix this issue,

```
plt.savefig("spec.png")
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```